# Multi org - connect parent to production CRM and connect BU to Test CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

I am looking for some assistance on the following, we are setting up multi org as we want to connect to a test and a production CRM enviroment. We are aware of the implications and are willing to except those. What I am just wondering is whether I can connect the parent to a different org then the BU, as all the use cases I see online the different business units are connect to different salesforce orgs and the parent is not used for connection.

Does anyone have experience with doing what we are considering or does any one know what are the implications of following our strategy.

Looking forward to some support.

Regards, 
Marloes

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. With Multi org connector made available, with Salesforce Orgs happens at the individual business unit level and makes no assumptions about integration with other business units. In our unit, we have 17 Business Units mapped to separate Salesforce orgs

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have done what your are saying before connecting multiple BU's to multiple Salesforce orgs. 

But what I want to do is connect Parent (enterprise level) to Salesforce org 1 and connect the business unit to Salesforce org 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect Parent BU(enterprise level) with production and child BU with sandbox.When you synchronized data extension in both the BU then you can see different name for enterprise and for child BU ex: Account_Salesdforce & Account_Salesforce_1. No implication is there you only have to take care about DE name when your are writing any query in Parent or in Child.